# Jquery failing to detect change in select in IE7&8 but works in FF

Tags: jquery

I can get this to run in IE9 and FF but does not work in IE7&8 can anybody point me in the right direction. Any ideas what to look out for?

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#page').change(function(){
        alert('--not-calling-in-IE8-or-IE7-Mode-Works-Fine-In-FF-');
        var url = 'galleryoptions.php?page=' + $('#page option:selected').val();
        $.getJSON(url, function(j){         
            var options = '<option value="0">None</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
            }
            $("#proj").html(options);
        });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<label for="page" style="margin-top:10px;padding:2px; margin-left:-15px;">P&aacute;gina</label>
<select id="page" name="page" type="text" style="width:135px; margin-top:8px;margin-bottom:8px;padding:2px; margin-left:10px;">
```

What I have tried:

I placed an onchange on the select and called an alert and it worked.
I placed an onchange on the select and called a function which never worked.

```
<select id="page" name="page" type="text" onchange="alert('This works')">

function dofn(){
  alert('This fails')
}

<select id="page" name="page" type="text" onchange="dofn();">
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'd check the HTML that you're generating - there's no problem with what you're trying to do (even in IE7). I just tested the following and it worked fine - all three selects generate an alert when they're changed

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#s3").change(function () {
                    alert("Select 3");
                });
            });

            function changeHandler() {
                alert("Select 2");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <select onchange="alert('Select 1');">
                <option value="1">first</option>
                <option value="2">sec</option>
            </select>
            <select onchange="changeHandler();">
                <option value="1">first</option>
                <option value="2">sec</option>
            </select>
            <select id="s3">
                <option value="1">first</option>
                <option value="2">sec</option>
            </select>
    </body>
</html>
```